# How do I utilize the same variable in both javascript code and asp.net razor mvc code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I utilize the same variable in both **JavaScript** code and **ASP.NET MVC Razor** code?

As you can see from the code below, I created a `dropdown` and filled it with data.

I want the selected item to be utilized in the below `div`.

- When the user clicks on an item, what is contained within that `div` is revealed
- Then the selected string item is used within the `if statement` within the `div`

What currently happens is, the selected item isn't globally accessible, causing the issues you can see below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="display-field" align="left">
        <select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="onChange()">
        @foreach (var lLMMI in lIM)
        {
            <option value="@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode">
                @locItem.Key.Loc.N (@lLMMI.Key.Loc.Code)
            </option>
        }
        </select>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
}

var itemselected = "";

<div>
    <script>
        function onChange() {
            var item = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
            $('#summary').show();
        }
    </script>

    <div id="summary">

        @foreach (var lLMMI in lIM)
        {
            if (@lLMMI.Key.Pro.PCode == itemselected.toString())
            {
                <summary>extra html elements are added etc.</summary>
            }
        }
```

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. C# (which is what Razor is running for you) is run *on the server*, and used to *generate* whatever is sent to the client. Your JavaScript is then run *on the client*, with no contact with the server at all (except through AJAX requests, which are something different entirely). [What are you *really* trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Looks like you want the summary to be filled with data called from the server, based on the selected value of the dropdown. This can be achieved by an Ajax call, giving the value as a parameter.

Comment: Certain functions will be called within the Summary based upon the selected item. But I need to know how to pass that selected item through from the dropdown to the if statement within the div above.

If you know how, that'd be fantastic

Comment: As Tomas indicated, you can't. The `if` statement is run on the server before it is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Javascript variable in the Razor code for two reasons:

- They don't exist at the same time
- They don't exist in the same place

The Razor code runs on the server to generate the page that is sent to the browser. When the page arrives to the browser it is parsed and the Javascript code runs. To use the Javascript variable in the Razor code would be a time paradox, because it would need to send the value back in time to change how the page was created, but keep the original time line in between...

There are basically two different ways of updating a page depending on input from the user:

- Reload the page, including the data in the request.
- Use an AJAX call to request that part of the page, including the data as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you the actual code right now, but here it goes.

You have the following options for your `dropdown`.

```
<option value="@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode">
    @locItem.Key.Loc.N (@lLMMI.Key.Loc.Code)
</option>
```

For example, you want to show `@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode + @lLMMI.Key.Product.PName + @lLMMI.Key.Product.PAddress`. Why not load what you will show to your options' values and show them when selected? Like:

```
<option value="@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode + @lLMMI.Key.Product.PName + @lLMMI.Key.Product.PAddress">
    @locItem.Key.Loc.N (@lLMMI.Key.Loc.Code)
</option>
```

And change the function to:

```
function onChange() {
    var myDropDown = document.getElementById("mydropdown");
    var myValue = myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("summary");
    fieldNameElement.innerHTML = myValue;
}
```

As others mentioned, you cannot play with **Razor** (server side) and **Javascript** (client side) like that. Think of **Razor** code running only once at the page load. If you want to do stuff after the page load, you need to assign your **Razor** variables to some client side elements and operate with client side code, **JavaScript** in your example.

Comment: I don't understand how the above allows me to utilize the selected drop-down item within my if statement. I apologise if I've missed something

Comment: Can you please provide what you want to show within `summary` like `@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode + @lLMMI.Key.Product.PName`?

Comment: What happens in summary doesn't matter. I just need in some fashion for the value being selected within the drop-down to be passed through to the itemselected variable

Comment: it says fieldNameElement.innerHTML = myValue;
But how does that relate to the variable  itemselected

Comment: myValue is the selected value of the dropdown. by that line, you show dropdown's selected value in the div with the id "summary". please read the javascript code, trying to understand.

Comment: How can I show a value I can't name etc. I think I'm misunderstanding you. Could you please modify my code above, or explain with an example - for clarity. Thanks

Comment: please just paste my javascript code (onChange function) to your original project, overwriting your function, and delete the contents of "summary" div. I don't know how can I help you more.

Comment: I already have pasted that function in.
But why would I delete the contents of summary div. This contains my functions, that honestly makes no sense.

Comment: that razor code will only write the first index value of the dropdown to summary. it won't work for selection changes in the dropdown.

Comment: So how is that applicable to my situation described in length above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63098/discussion-between-isthatso-and-decepticon).