# In asp.net razor mvc How do I utilize the selected dropdown item within a if statement, within a div?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**This question is not a duplicate.**

**That above question, suggested to be a duplicate asked how to use the same variable between Java and asp.net.**

**Whereas this question accepts the previous isn't possible and is instead asking what other methodologies are possible?**

In asp.net razor mvc How do I utilize the selected dropdown item within a if statement, within a div?

As you can see from the code below, I created a `dropdown` and filled it with data.

I want the selected item to be utilized in the below `div`.

- When the user clicks on an item, what is contained within that `div` is revealed
- Then the selected string item is used within the `if statement` within the `div`

What currently happens is, the selected item isn't globally accessible, causing the issues you can see below.

But as I've been told by knowledgable others, you can't utilise the same variable between `javascript` and `asp.net` `mvc` `razor`. So the below will not work.

How can this be accomplished? (utilization of the selected dropdown item within a if statement, within a div?)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="display-field" align="left">
        <select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="onChange()">
        @foreach (var lLMMI in lIM)
        {
            <option value="@lLMMI.Key.Product.PCode">
                @locItem.Key.Loc.N (@lLMMI.Key.Loc.Code)
            </option>
        }
        </select>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
}

var itemselected = "";

<div>
    <script>
        function onChange() {
            var item = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
            $('#summary').show();
        }
    </script>

    <div id="summary">

        @foreach (var lLMMI in lIM)
        {
            if (@lLMMI.Key.Pro.PCode == itemselected.toString())
            {
                <summary>extra html elements are added etc.</summary>
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I utilize the same variable in both javascript code and asp.net razor mvc code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377648/how-do-i-utilize-the-same-variable-in-both-javascript-code-and-asp-net-razor-mvc)

Comment: Its not a duplicate as that question asked how to use the same variable between Java and asp.net.

Comment: Whereas this question accepts the previous isn't possible and is asking instead what other methodologies are possible?

Comment: The **accepted answer** showed 2 ways of doing this - reload the page or use ajax to update the existing page.

Comment: I've been told in the thread described earlier that you can't utilise a javascript variable in asp.net. Hence I'm stuck

Comment: Handle the dropdown change event to get the selected value then use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view based on the value, then update the DOM with the returned result.

Comment: I'm sure by my explanations so far,  you can tell I don't know how to do what your suggesting. Could you please show a coding example. Thanks

Comment: OK, I'll post a generic answer shortly that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Please relate it to my situation described

Answer (score 1):

You should use only javaScript. Update your code as follows:

```
<script>
    var serverCode = "@lLMMI.Key.Pro.PCode"; // get the server value on JS
    function onChange() {
        var localCode = $("#mydropdown").val();
        if(localCode == serverCode)
           $("#extrasummary").show();

        $('#summary').show();
    }
</script>

<div id="summary">
    <div id="extrasummary" style="display:none">extra html elements are added etc.</div>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: The value selected needs to be passed on to the if statement, not just hide and show div

Comment: But you have it as a variable in your JS code. Can you not use it there?

Comment: While this code simplifies the implementation and will be faster (will be best for situation where options are < 10), it would not fit in cases where 'lLMMI.Key.Pro.PCode' has many option. You will have to handle each case in cshtml code.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the change event of your dropdown and make an ajax call to return a partial view that you can add to the DOM using jquery [.load(](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). Note in your view remove the `@foreach` so you just have

```
<div id="summary"></div>
```

which is where the returned html will be displayed

Script

```
$('#mydropdown').change(function() {
  var selectedID = $(this).val();
  var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "YourController")';
  $('#summary').load(url, { ID: selectedID });
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int ID)
{
  var model = // Get the details based on the selected ID
  return PartialView("Details", model);
}
```

Note also, remove the `onchange="onChange()` from your `<select>`. I also recommend you learn to use [@Html.DropDownListFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx) for generating you `<select>` controls

Comment: How does this pass the value to the if statement described above??

Comment: As I noted, just get rid of all the code in between the `<div id="summary">` tags. The `if` statement is meaningless because its rendered on the server before its sent to the client, so at that point the user has not selected an item. The script I posted gets the value of the selected item when the user chooses it, passes it to a controller method which returns a partial view containing the details based on that value (I don't know what you want to show so you will need create the partial) then inserts that into the `<div>`

Comment: This solution has advantage of keeping view as dumb as possible (key goal of MVC). The controller will decide what to display based on user selection. +1 for taking time and writing it up... :)

Comment: How do I hide (or stop the rendering) of what's generated within that div then until the user has selected an item from the drop-down. Then upon the user's selection generate what's within the div,  utilising the selected drop-down value as expressed above

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. If delete all your code/html between the `<div id="summary">` tags then nothing is shown initially. When you select an item, the details of that item will be shown. When you select another item, a new set of details will be shown in its place. Just give it a go.

Comment: But if I delete all my html code from within div summary tags where else should I place it. As I want that to be formed relative to the selection hence why the if statement was intended to verify whether the information being displayed corresponded to the actual  item selected.

Comment: The script will display the details in that `div` when the user makes a selection. Or do you mean you want to display some initial details when the page first loads (before the user makes a selection)?

Comment: When the page loads, I'm wanting nothing in the div to generate but when the user makes a selection within the dropdown. The generation of the div begins and the if statement uses the selected value to determine which values to the show to the user

Comment: Which is exactly what the code in my answer does. Perhaps if you try it you might understand.

Comment: I have, but as described earlier. I don't know where to place the html code removed from the div summary. Similarly i don't know what I'm supposed to put after model within controller.

Comment: I don't understand how I would be utilising this code within the removed html

Comment: You don't put the _code removed from the div summary_ anywhere - it does not work! The (does not work) `if` statement rendered _extra html elements are added etc._ based on the selected value. That what the controller code needs to do. Render a partial view based on the value of the selected item you pass to the method.

Comment: To start with (for testing purposes), create a partial view `Details.cshtml` with the following html: `<span>The current time is:</span><span>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</span>`. In the controller replace `return PartialView("Details", model);` with `return PartialView("Details");` When your select a item from the dropdown, your will see the current time displayed.

Comment: That doesn't do anything. When I click the drop-down, nothing happens. Was I supposed to do something with var model = as didn't know what to put there

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Have you included jquery? Is the controller name correct? Its late, I'll look again in the morning.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the project has access to jquery. Yes it's named correctly.

Comment: @coverage. I have already created a project using the code I have posted at it works fine. Put breakpoints in you script and in he controller method and debug it.